# iPhone Sandbox rules file

Tags: iphone, sandbox, rules

Where can I find the application sandbox rules file for 3.0 firmware? I remember seeing it somewhere around in 2.x, but now can't find it.

Answer (score 3):

- The First Rule of Application Sandbox Rules is you don't talk about Application Sandbox Rules.
- The Second Rule of Application Sandbox Rules, is to look in 'The Application Sandbox' section of Apple's iPhone OS Programming Guide

The Guide can be found at [http://developer.apple.com/iphone](http://developer.apple.com).

Comment: I need the exact rules file, not the description.